# How made button works without navigation link (swiftui)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

```swift
Button(action: {print("tapped")}) {
    HStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: HomePageView()){
            Text("Sign In")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

so I made the login screen and the button with navigation link and it works to homepage but in the homepage has a back button if I touch it, it back to the login screen again and how to solve it with navigation link or without navigation link

Comment: show us the relevant code you have already, so we can help you achieve what you ask.

Comment: ok thnk for suggestion im new here by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to hide the backbutton, you need to add the .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) modifier to the navigation link

```
Button(action: {print("tapped")}){
                    HStack{
                        NavigationLink( destination: HomePageView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)){
                        Text("Sign In")
                        Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
```